# Adding a filter expression to a JSONIterator Find function call

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

What is the correct syntax for a filter expression to query a JSON object with a specific attribute string value inside an array, using bracket notation?

I am limited to bracket notation because dot notation won't work in Delphi when there is a quote or apostrophe inside the filter expression.

> Use [] to access object properties that do contain a quoting character
>   in their name. For example, use root['child.name'] or
>   root["child.name"] to access the child.name property of the root
>   object.

I've used an online JSON path evaluator against this JSON and come up with the expression `result["elements"][?(@.name == 'Training Seminar - Nov 9')]`. In the online evaluator, this path works fine and returns the exact object I'm looking for. However, when I run it in Delphi I get an exception that says

> EJSONPathException: Invalid index for array: ?(@.name == 'Training
>   Seminar - Nov 9')

My question is, what is the correct syntax for a filter expression to query a JSON object with a specific attribute string value inside an array, using bracket notation?

MCVE for this as a console application, including the JSON.

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.JSON.Builders, System.JSON.Readers, System.JSON.Types;

const JsonStr = '{' +
'   "result":{     ' +
'      "elements":[   ' +
'         {              ' +
'            "id":"ML_1HMloeUjEFgKaC9",' +
'            "name":"Utilization Survey",' +
'         },' +
'         {' +
'            "id":"ML_1zQjGtGXFPkEo6N",' +
'            "name":"Training Seminar - Nov 9",' +
'         }' +
'      ]' +
'   },' +
'   "meta":{' +
'      "httpStatus":"200 - OK",' +
'      "requestId":"ef2afd6e-3fd9-4fdf-a8fe-c935c147a0af"' +
'   }' +
'}';

procedure RunIt;
var Reader : TJsonTextReader;
  Iterator : TJsonIterator;
  StringReader : TStringReader;
  Found : Boolean;
begin
  StringReader := TStringReader.Create(JsonStr);
  Reader := TJsonTextReader.Create(StringReader);
  Iterator := TJsonIterator.Create(Reader);
  try
    Found := Iterator.Find('result["elements"][?(@.name == ''Training Seminar - Nov 9'')]');
    //The value of Found is false or an exception is raised because of bad syntax in the filter expression
    WriteLn(BoolToStr(Found));
    ReadLn;
  finally
    Iterator.Free;
    Reader.Free;
    StringReader.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    RunIt;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      Readln;
    end
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use expressions at all, because they are not implemented. Whether in dot notation or bracket notation. Excerpt from official documentation of [System.JSON.TJSONPathParser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.JSON.TJSONPathParser).

> These operators do not support special expressions, they only
>   support actual values (object properties or array indexes).

However in this case, it can be achieved in a slightly more complicated way.

```
procedure RunIt;
var
  lJSON, lValue, lName: TJSONValue;
  lFound : Boolean;
begin
  lFound := False;
  lJSON := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonStr);
  if Assigned(lJSON) then
  try
    if lJSON.TryGetValue('result.elements', lValue) and (lValue is TJSONArray) then
    begin
      for lValue in TJSONArray(lValue) do
      begin
        lFound := lValue.TryGetValue('name', lName) and (lName.Value = 'Training Seminar - Nov 9');
        if lFound then
          Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    lJSON.Free;
  end;
  WriteLn(BoolToStr(lFound));
  ReadLn;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @Triber. Works like a charm.